# Virtuosity.Fody and Unity project?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, fody

I'm trying to use Virtuosity.Fody in a Unity project and I've followed the steps to install it, but it's not actually doing any weaving. The unit tests that depend on virtual methods fail if I remove the keyword, which Virtuosity should be adding...

Comment: The complete instructions for using Virtuosity.Fody are located [here](https://github.com/Fody/Virtuosity).  Note that you have to follow *all* the steps, not just some of them.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I did carefully read and follow those instructions.